# Remote Tomee Client cannot access EJB from JBOSS 7.1.1 server

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, remoting, openejb, apache-tomee

To begin with I am a newbie to OpenEJB standards. So please forgive my lack of knowledge on the topic.

I have a server application running on JBOSS 7.1.1 AS. 
I want to create a web client running on Tomee and be able to communicate with JBOSSS server (to use EJB injection in my webclient)

I tried adding jboss-client.jar to my webclient but since Tomee has its own openejb implementation, I was getting ClassNotFoundExceptions org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientConfiguration

Following was my contextInitalisation code

```
Properties ejbProperties = new Properties();
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
    ejbProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connections", "default");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.host", host);
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.port", port);
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS", "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER"); // needed for forcing authentication over remoting (i.e. if you have a custom login module)
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false"); // needed for a login module that requires the password in plaintext
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "true");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.username", username);
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.default.password", md5);

    final EJBClientConfiguration ejbClientConfiguration = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(ejbProperties);
    // here, a UnresolvedAddressException or SaslException is thrown but cannot be catched
    // so if server address is wrong or login cannot be determined
    final ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(ejbClientConfiguration);
    EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);
    EJBClientContext.getCurrent().registerInterceptor(0, new ClientInterceptor());

    context = new InitialContext(ejbProperties);
```

So i retried creating InitialContext using OpenEJBproperties in my client instead

```
ejbProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
    ejbProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ejbd://" + host + ":" + port);
    ejbProperties.put("java.naming.security.principal", username);
    ejbProperties.put("java.naming.security.credentials", md5);
```

Now i get following errors console/log
WARNING: RequestFailed{server=ejbd://localhost:4447} JNDI_LOOKUP:/ejb:XXX {error=Cannot determine server protocol version: Received OEJP/4.6 : Failed to read spec: [0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 9, 49]}

SEVERE: Servlet /Web threw load() exception
org.apache.openejb.client.ClientRuntimeException: Invalid response from server: -1
    at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.lookup(JNDIContext.java:468)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)

On a side note I also see these warnings in my console 
WARNING: jar 'XXX\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.
Apr 10, 2015 10:31:51 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
WARNING: jar 'XXX\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-client.jar' contains offending class: javax.transaction.Transaction. It will be ignored.

I am struggling with this issue for quiet some time now. Any help is highly appreciated..

Thank You